# Meaning of たァ after verb in dictionary form

Tags: grammar

> 「入浴剤まで置いてあるたァ、なんだか今日はかあさんの奴、気が利くじゃねぇか。」
>   Even bath salts have been put out. Somehow, today, mother's (things?) are thoughtful aren't they?

I'm reasonably happy with てある: something has been done by somebody and the state remains. But what is た doing on the end here?

Also stuck on how to translate 奴. I fear I've got this translation quite wrong.

Comment: 「の」 in 「かあさんの」 is appositive.   Also, 「かあさん」 refers to the speaker's wife, not his mom.

Comment: @l'électeur So can I replace this の with という or have I misunderstood what you mean by appositive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

たぁ here is a contraction of とは (an expression of surprise); I think it's Tokyo dialect. And (person)の奴 is simply a discourteous or familiar way of referring to the person in question. This whole passage is very colloquial.

'Wow, she's even got the bath salts out! Ain't the missus thoughtful today?' is my translation.

Comment: たあ is Tokyo dialect alright.  Kinda slangy and highly masculine as well.